# Number of SOAP Integration flows

Tags: apex, integration, soap

In REST, as per the REST API developer guide, we have the following three different types of flows.

1.Username/Password flow

2.User Agent flow

3.Webserver flow

Do we have any such different types of integration for SOAP integration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually those are not rest integration flows, they are [OAuth flows](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com) which help you to get an access token that you can use to subsequently make calls to SalesForce from another system.

Rest and SOAP are used to create web services. Now, to access salesforce from any external system, you will be required to have an access token which you can get by using your organisations enterprise or partner WSDL or if you want users to authenticate themselves prior to using your application, you may use OAuth flows as you have stated in your question.

For more insight on SOAP and REST Web Services, you can read the following documentation by salesforce.

[SOAP](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services.htm) and [REST](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the various types are based on OAuth and not based on REST....so I can assume there is only one variant of SOAP integration..am i right ?..

Comment: @user25311 I do not understand what is meant by a variant but yes, I see that there are two ways to create web services i.e via rest or via soap.

Comment: @user25311 there are different implementations of SOAP depending on what you think of as an "implementation". You'll need to read the documentation. Unlike REST, all SOAP is XML based. But, there's more than one way to send it (with and w/o encryption, etc).